# Github projects with databases

Tags: git, github, yii

Hi (sorry if this has been asked before but I couldn't find the answer)

I am looking at using Git (probably Github) for a project coming up that I will be working on. The project will be using Yii framework which needs a set of database tables etc. While we're working in development, we'll need to add/edit/delete tables, but the Production area will not have these tables.  How do we address the differences between environments?

The only thought I have now is to somehow get the Schema of the SQL including the data into a .sql file and have use a script, which would automatically update our database, be a part of our project (which will be apart of Github). Is this the best idea? or is there something I am missing?

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't get the github business, github as the tag description explains is a hosting facility for git repositories

Comment: basically it will host the repository and the files for each different developer working on the project allowing them to have their own branches etc. the whole bit about the branches is where I am uncertain about the MySQL database not having the correct tables up to date between the branches

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is generally not a good idea to keep all of your database data in source control. I would suggest using the built in [migration tool](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.migration) to keep everyone's databases up to date. If you want to avoid an empty production database, I'd suggest making a "seed" file, with some minimal data to be prepopulated, like this:

```
INSERT INTO `tbl_user`
(`email`, `username`)
VALUES
('admin@example.com','admin'),
('guest@example.com','guest')
;
```

Comment: ok thank you, I was more thinking of when multiple people working on it in different environments and adding extra tables that others do not have existing when coming to use the same files etc.

Comment: this is exactly what migrations are made for, actually. you write the migration which describes a change from one database state to another, and when you update your code, you run any outstanding migrations as well to keep everything in line.

Answer (score 1):

Do the tables have to be in the same git repository? You could create two repositories (one for the tables and one for the code) and use Git's [submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) feature to group them under one repository.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea thanks, is it a feature as well as Github? I haven't come across the feature before thanks.